# Is there a database/application that sorts characters based on pronunciation, radical, frequency; and disyllabic compound words by frequency?

Tags: characters, traditional-vs-simplified, database

Researchers have used/cited the Academia Sinica Balanced Corpus of Modern Chinese for finding disyllabic compound words and characters with top-bottom and left-right construction. However I haven't found this information/filter on the site -- only sorting by part of speech.

The Traditional Chinese Psycholinguistic Database has been helpful but not comprehensive enough.

I'm designing materials for a research project comparing simplified readers and traditional readers, so being able to compare frequencies between characters of the two systems is important. I haven't found a research article that compared the two systems AND provided an appendix of the materials. any suggestions?

Various sources categorize simplification methods differently and only list some examples. Does a more comprehensive list exist?

where can I find a list of simplified radicals and their traditional counterparts? a list of disyllabic compound words sorted by frequency?

Any resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this pdf, [Simplified Chinese Mapping Chart (1956)](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52801895e4b04258782fb399/t/5286e83ae4b01a998999f1bf/1384572986667/SimplifiedChineseMappingChart1956.pdf), could help:
This is 简化字总表(Simplified characters full list), an official list that includes 1) simplified characters that may not be used as radicals; 2) simplified radicals and simplified characters that may be used as radicals; 3) frequently used characters.

Another even more comprehensive list with versions and alterations through years can be found on wikipedia [简化字总表](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AE%80%E5%8C%96%E5%AD%97%E6%80%BB%E8%A1%A8) (Chineses only). I guess you would get what you were looking for by translating that page!